# Recommendations for multiple migration runs?

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

Could anyone provide any best practices about multiple migration runs? Moving from TFS 2017.3.1 to Azure DevOps Service. Dealing with a fair number of work items (32k). Of course, TSTU throttling is making the run take a long time, so I was thinking of pushing what I could up front, then a second pass to pick up the new work items since the first big push. So...enabling UpdateSourceReflectedId would set the ReflectedWorkItemId on the source items that have already been migrated.  But what happens if someone changes a work item that has already been pushed?  Would the history delta get picked up?  How is that typically resolved...I was thinking maybe a Querybit like: ReflectedWorkItemId <> '' and ChangedDate > (last run time), but is that necessary? Those already exist on target...would ReplayRevisions pick up only the missing changes? TIA...

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following for large runs:

- Open work items edited in last 90 days
- Closed work items edited in last 90 days
- open out to more days in chunks

The important thing to note is that links are created only when both ends of the link exist.

After a long run you can then rerun "edited in last month" to bring any changes a cross.

Changes to avoid in the Source:

- changing work item type
- moving work item between team project

We handle these, but loosly.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the suggestions Martin. Good thing the two "changes to avoid in source" are not at play here.  I'll cut the date range down a lot so that I can get a better feel for the exact behavior without having to wait for such a long time between initial runs. Another question: according to the documentation on GitHub, if NodeStructuresMigration has been merged into WorkItemMigration and marked as obsolete, then how could I run NodeStructuresMigration before TeamMigration or WorkItemQueryMigration processors?  Otherwise, the areas and iterations would not exist on target yet.

Comment: You can still run the old NodeStructuresMigration processor, it has not been removed.

Comment: Could you please clarify what a "new one" means?  Are you saying that there's a refactor of the NodeStructuresMigration processor in a recent version?  I believe that I tried it with 11.7.5, and it wasn't working.  Have slept since then, so I'll try it again...I usually stay a few versions behind your bleeding edge unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: We are on v11.9.20 and have added https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/Processors/TfsAreaAndIterationProcessor.html

Comment: Great!  I'll bump up to 11.9.20 and give it a try.  Thanks Martin!

Comment: The-Everett can you please mark this as answered?